# Turing's Encryption 2.0 (MIT lecture)

Tags: number-theory, computer-science, cryptography

I am learning mathematics for computer science on  OpenCourseWare.

Encryption: The message m can be any integer in the set $\{0,1,2,\dots,p−1\}$; in par­ticular, the message is no longer required to be a prime. The sender encrypts 
the message $m$ to produce $m^∗$
by computing:
$$m^∗ = \operatorname{remainder}(mk,p).$$

Multiplicative inverses are the key to decryption in Turing’s code. Specfically, 
we can recover the original message by multiplying the encoded message by the 
inverse of the key:
\begin{align*}
m*k^{-1}
&\cong \operatorname{remainder}(mk,p) k^{-1} &&
\text{(the def. (14.8) of $m^*$)} \\
&\cong (mk) k{^-1} \pmod p && \text{(by Cor. 14.5.2)} \\
&\cong m \pmod p.
\end{align*}
This shows that $m*k^{-1}$ is congruent to the original message $m$. Since $m$ was in 
the range $0,1,\dots,p-1$, we can recover it exactly by taking a remainder

Second last step with how $k$ and $k^{-1}$ is 1 since $k$ and $k^{-1}$ are not multiplicative inverse but modulo $p$ inverse.

$p|(k-k^{-1})-1$, hence you cant just write $k*k^{-1}$ as $1$.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Thanks.
P.S. Sorry i had to copy parts of text from a different question.

Comment: Note that this "Turing encryption" (made up name...there is no such thing) is a very bad mono-alphabetic cipher, which is even broken by one plaintext-ciphertext pair. It seems to be an excuse to introduce modular inverses.

Comment: Read and apply [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) while you're at it as well.

Comment: You  multiply $m^*$  by an integer $ k'$ such that $kk'\equiv 1\pmod p. $ Thus $k'm^*\equiv m \pmod p$

Answer (score 3):

You are working in the ring of integers $\bmod p$.  Although the message need not be prime, the modulus should be.  In that case every integer not divisible by $p$ has an inverse-the ring is actually a field.  In that ring (field) $kk^{-1}$ does equal $1$

Comment: Can you please provide a more detailed explanation. I am currently a novice. An example will help.

Comment: For a simple example, let $p=7$ and choose $k=2$.  We note that $2 \cdot 4 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$, so in this field $4=2^{-1}$.  If the message is $5$, we encrypt it as $5 \cdot 2 =3$ and decrypt it as $3 \cdot 4=5$

Comment: Understood the example, one last question, what do you mean by Ring Of Numbers and ring(field)?

Comment: Ring and field are two types of algebraic structure.  Each comes with a set of axioms and any structure that satisfies them qualifies.  Intuitively, rings are like the integers in that you can add, subtract, multiply, and distribute multiplication over addition.  You may not be able to divide.  Fields are like the reals in that you can do all four operations (except divide by zero).